# How can a minor accept payments online?

Tags: united-states, online-payment, minor

Are there ways other than cryptocurrencies for minors to receive online payments without an adult intermediary?

Comment: Why do you need adult intermediary? And why, if you do, cryptocurrencies would be an exception?

Comment: @littleadv most if not all payment services only allow users over 18; cryptocurrencies (at least decentralized ones like Bitcoin) don't really have terms of service or any kind of agreement other than the software license, so there are no restrictions on who can use them.

Comment: That's because you're not legally able to enter binding contracts, and how you're paid doesn't matter. Technically you're probably not bound by the software licenses as well, for the same reason. That's probably a question more suitable to law@SE.

Comment: @littleadv minors are not allowed to use software? very weird!

Comment: @littleadv I could stop using the software and no longer be bound by the license. Many licenses allow adults to do that too; I just have a legally guaranteed right to do so as a minor. The licensor is bound just like they would be with an adult user, and I am bound as long as I use the software. It's more problematic with the minor being the licensor. I am an open source software developer, but because I'm a minor, I technically could revoke the license at any time, and some people might not want to use my software because of that. Of course, I would never do that, but I do have a legal right

Comment: to. (Filler text to make comment long enough)

Comment: @user253751 money transfer requires a contract. Even if the OP receives bitcoins, they'd need to convert them to currency at some point, and then a contract would be required.

Comment: @littleadv https://law.stackexchange.com/a/58279/44937

Answer (score 1):

Minors can own and run a business; but they cannot use the software and mobile applications needed for payment acceptance.

Solution: hire an adult to do your business's bookkeeping and payment acceptance. The adult can log in as a legitimate user of Quickbooks or Stripe.

Comment: Who pays the taxes on this case?